# Constrained Composition of Tuples

Tags: python, tuples, combinatorics

I have this problem of combinatorics:
Let m=(m1,...,mk) be a vector of k positive integers. A k-composition (a1,...,ak) of n is m-constrained if ai≤mi for all 1≤i≤k. For example, (1,1,3) and (2,1,2) are the only (2,1,4)-constrined 3-partitions of 5.

Write a function constrained_compositions that takes a natural number n and a vector m of k positive integers, and prints the set of all m-constrained k-compositions of n. Note that k can be inferred from m.

Googling found this useful function:

```
def compositions(k, n):
# inputs: k and n are of type 'int'
# output: a set of tuples
assert n > k > 1
to_process = [[i] for i in range(1, n+1)]
while to_process:
    l = to_process.pop()
    s = sum(l)
    le = len(l)
    for i in range(1, n-s+1): 
        news = s + i
        if news <= n:
            newl = list(l)
            newl.append(i)
            if le == k-1 and news == n:
                yield tuple(newl)
            elif le < k-1 and news < n:
                to_process.append(newl)
```

And implemented to get the tuples that match the constrain like this:

```
def constrained_compositions(n, m):
# inputs: n is of type 'int' and m is a list of integers
# output: a set of tuples
k = len(m)
max_num = max(m)
l = []
comp = list(compositions(k,n))
for i in comp:
    for j in i:
        if j <= max_num:
            l.append(i)
print(set(l))
```

But this is my result:

```
{(2, 3, 2), (2, 1, 4), (4, 2, 1), (5, 1, 1), (3, 3, 1), (3, 2, 2), (3, 1, 3), (1, 5, 1), (1, 4, 2), (2, 2, 3), (2, 4, 1), (1, 2, 4), (4, 1, 2), (1, 1, 5), (1, 3, 3)}
```

And it should be:

```
{(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 2)}
```

Thanks in advance for your help?

Comment: Did you try making `l` a set, instead of a list?

Comment: Nope, let me try it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part in your code that is a bit off, is that you only consider the max value from `m` and check all elements of your compositions against it, without regard for their actual position.

Here is a recursive generator that produces the constrained compositions directly:

```
def constrained_compositions(n, m):
    if n == 0 and not m:
        yield ()
    if n < 0 or not m:
        return
    for i in range(1, min(n, m[0])+1):
        for cc in constrained_compositions(n-i, m[1:]):
            yield (i,) + cc

>>> list(constrained_compositions(7, [3, 2, 5]))
[(1, 1, 5), (1, 2, 4), (2, 1, 4), (2, 2, 3), (3, 1, 3), (3, 2, 2)]
```

This defines a success and a failure base case. Otherwise, it makes sure the first element of the composition `i` is within the given restriction `<= m[0]` and recurses with the remainders of both `n` and `m`: `n-i` and `m[1:]`

Comment: Interesting example let me check this out!!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me fine:

```
def constrained_compositions(n, m):
    C = set()

    
    def help_comp(k, l):
        D = set()
        if k == 1:
            for i in range(m[0]):
                D.add((i+1,))
        else:
            for j in help_comp(k=k-1, l=l):
                for i in range(m[(len(list(j)))]):
                    i=i+1
                    if i <= m[(len(list(j)))]:
                        D.add((j)+(i,))
        return D

    if len(m) == 1 & m[0] != n:
        return C

    if n == 0 and m[0] !=n:
        return C

    if len(m) == 1 and m[0] == n:
        C.add((n,))

    else:
        for i in range(m[-1]):
            i=i+1
            for j in help_comp(k=len(m)-1, l=n):
                if sum(list((i,)+(j))) == n:
                    if i <= m[-1]:
                        C.add((j)+(i,))
    return C
```

Comment: Can you explain how it fixes the problem instead of just giving the code?

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected and cleaned up the code.
First it creates a helper function which creates a set of tuples.

It first creates one-element tuples, each smaller or equal to m's first element. Then it adds one element per each recursion where new element is smaller than equal to the corresponding element of m.

In the main function the empty set C is created and the helper function is being called for len(m)-1 number of the tuples. In a for cycle of the range of the last element of m a new tuple is being added to C, if sum of helper function's tuple and m's last item equals to n.